# 3-bit serial input bubble sort in VHDL not sorting

Tags: sorting, vhdl, bubble-sort

I am trying to design a 3-bit serial input bubble sort and have not been able to get the output to actually sort.

Unfortunately, I am not very familiar with VHDL, or programming in general.

I have read that a potential problem of mine is the way I am using signals and assigning them within my process. However, when I tried correcting that and got it to compile, my output was broken.

There was another question about bubble sort in VHDL using arrays that I also tried to base mine off of, but was also unsuccessful. The main thing I tried from that was the `for i in ___ to ___ loop` process.

Below is my code and test bench that I have most recently been using.

Any advice or explanations would be greatly appreciated!

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity bubble_sort_bs is
    generic (
        width : integer := 3);
    port ( 
        X0, X1, X2 : in std_logic;
        Y0, Y1, Y2 : out std_logic;
        clk, enable : in std_logic);
end entity bubble_sort_bs;

architecture bubble_sort_bs_behav of bubble_sort_bs is
    signal comb_out : std_logic;
    signal inp : std_logic_vector((width-1) downto 0);
    signal inp1 : std_logic_vector((width-1) downto 0);
    signal inp2 : std_logic_vector((width-1) downto 0);
    signal pass_in, pass_out : std_logic_vector((width-1) downto 0);
    signal outp : std_logic_vector((width-1) downto 0); --trash
    signal x_vector : std_logic_vector((width-1) downto 0);
begin 
    x_vector <= X0 & X1 & X2;
    Y0 <= pass_out(2);
    Y1 <= pass_out(1);
    Y2 <= pass_out(0);

    Output : process(all)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            if enable <= '1' then
                inp1 <= x_vector;
                inp2 <= pass_in;
            end if;
        end if;

        if inp1 > inp2 then  --x_vector
            comb_out <= '1';
            outp <= inp1;
            pass_in <= inp2;
        elsif inp2 > inp1 then --x_vector
            comb_out <= '0';
            outp <= inp2;
            pass_in <= inp1;
            ----inp2 <= inp1;
        elsif inp2 = inp1 then 
            comb_out <= '0';
            outp <= inp2;
            pass_in <= inp1;
        end if;
        pass_out <= outp;
    end process Output;
end architecture bubble_sort_bs_behav;
```

Testbench:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity bubble_sort_bs_tb is
end entity bubble_sort_bs_tb;

architecture tb_behav of bubble_sort_bs_tb is
    component bubble_sort_bs
        generic (
            width : integer);
        port (
            X0, X1, X2 : in std_logic;
            Y0, Y1, Y2 : out std_logic;
            clk, enable : std_logic
        );
    end component;
    constant bit_width : integer := 3;
    signal inp, outp : std_logic_vector((bit_width-1) downto 0);
    signal t_clk, t_enable : std_logic := '0';
begin
    U1 : bubble_sort_bs 
        generic map (bit_width)
        port map (
            X0 => inp(0),
            X1 => inp(1),
            X2 => inp(2),
            Y0 => outp(0),
            Y1 => outp(1),
            Y2 => outp(2),
            clk => t_clk,
            enable => t_enable
        );

    t_clk <= not t_clk after 5 ns;
    test_process : process
    begin
        inp <= "001";
        t_enable <= '1';
        wait for 20 ns;

        inp <= "100";
        t_enable <= '1';
        wait for 20 ns;

        inp <= "111";
        t_enable <= '1';
        wait for 20 ns;

        inp <= "000";
        t_enable <= '1';
        wait for 20 ns;

        wait; 
    end process;
end tb_behav;
```

Comment: You say you're not "familiar with programming in general". VHDL is _not_ a programming language - it is a _hardware description language_. When you write VHDL, you are designing hardware. You are right: the way you are assigning signals in the process is wrong. But, in fact, your code is very mixed up. I suggest you take a step back and larn some more VHDL, particular the coding style, particularly how what your write in VHDL relates to the hardware.

Comment: You might like to read [this](https://www.doulos.com/knowhow/vhdl_designers_guide/an_example_design_entity/) on my company's website. Keep clicking on 'Next' until you get to "A Mix Of Useful Tips" and then make sure you look at the "Sequential Processes" tip at least.

Answer (score 0):

Okay there are multiple things wrong with your code.
First of all your mapping from input to `x_vector` has the bits reversed, which you also do at your output. 
 
Next `pass_in` will never get a value, resulting in that your first comparison `inp1 > inp2` always is true. So what your actually doing is giving an input signal comparing it with nothing and then returning it a clock cycle later. [See Picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBd7j.png) 
To do a bubble sort you at least need to have two inputs in the beginning.

As said by others try some tutorials to get more familiar with VHDL before continuing. I can recommend the [asic-world tutorial](http://www.asic-world.com/vhdl/tutorial.html). 
Good luck!